# ISO-8859-1 encoding and binary data preservation

Tags: java, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I read in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913264/eclipse-vs-tomcat-deployment-exported-war-partially-fails-while-the-project#comment22524058_15745520) to an answer by @Esailija to a question of mine that

> ISO-8859-1 is the only encoding to fully retain the original binary data, with exact byte<->codepoint matches

I also read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520954/281545) by @AaronDigulla that :

> In Java, ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a ISO-Latin1) is a 1:1 mapping

I need some insight on this. This will fail (as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720995/281545)) :

```
// \u00F6 is ö
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("\u00F6".getBytes("utf-8")));
// prints [-61, -74]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("\u00F6".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
// prints [-10]
```

#### Questions

1. I admit I do not quite get it - *why does it not get the bytes in the code above* ?
2. Most importantly, ***where is this*** (*byte preserving behavior of* `ISO-8859-1`) ***specified*** - links to source, or JSL would be nice. Is it the only encoding with this property ?
3. Is it related to `ISO-8859-1` being the [default default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659567/281545) ?

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544965/why-new-stringbytes-enc-getbytesenc-does-not-return-the-original-byte-array) for nice counter examples from other charsets.

Comment: -10 is the base-10 signed value of 0xF6. Try `byte b = -10;
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF));`

Comment: @JBNizet :This I know - what I am asking about is the quoted "ISO-8859-1 is the only encoding to fully retain the original binary data" in java - that's what I do not quite get - what you gave does print `f6` - what are the bytes contained in `"\u00F6"` ? [-61, -74] or [-10] ?

Comment: Err, you just said that you knew that -10 and f6 are the same byte, represented differently. So the bytes contained in 0x00F6 are 0 are F6 in base 16, or 0 and -10 in signed-base-10.

Comment: @JBNiz : Why then it does not print [0, -10] - supposing that  ISO-8859-1 is byte preserving - that is what I do not get - the reported "byte preserving" behavior of  `ISO-8859-1`  in java.

Comment: OK. Now I get what you mean. See my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`"\u00F6"` is not a byte array. It's a string containing a single char. Execute the following test instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = new byte[] {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xf6};
    String s = new String(b, "ISO-8859-1"); // decoding
    byte[] b2 = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); // encoding
    System.out.println("Are the bytes equal : " + Arrays.equals(b, b2)); // true
}
```

To check that this is true for any byte, just improve the code an loop through all the bytes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] b = new byte[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = (byte) i;
    }
    String s = new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");
    byte[] b2 = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println("Are the bytes equal : " + Arrays.equals(b, b2));
}
```

ISO-8859-1 is a standard encoding. So the language used (Java, C# or whatever) doesn't matter.

Here's a [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) that claims that every byte is covered:

> In 1992, the IANA registered the character map ISO_8859-1:1987, more commonly known by its preferred MIME name of ISO-8859-1 (note the extra hyphen over ISO 8859-1), a superset of ISO 8859-1, for use on the Internet. This map assigns the C0 and C1 control characters to the unassigned code values **thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you - this answers 1 - I really need some authoritative link to ascertain/deny 2) - or some explanation - namely the byte preserving behavior of `ISO-8859-1` - and that it is the only one (in java and possibly other languages I guess like C#). For other charsets see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544965/why-new-stringbytes-enc-getbytesenc-does-not-return-the-original-byte-array

Comment: Thanks - do you believe it is the ***only*** `ENCODING` with this property : `byte[] b = newByteArray(); Arrays.equals(b, new String(b, ENCODING).getBytes(ENCODING)); // always true` ?

Comment: I don't know if it's the only one, no.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it is the only one where the decoded code point's value is also the byte's value it was decoded from (`\u00F6 <-> 0xF6`). That's what I meant. So you have the decoded string, and encoded bytes, then it is always `(byte)str.charAt(i) == bytes[i]` for arbitrary binary data where `str` is `new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it is also a rare property but not unique to ISO-8859-1 for a lossless round-trip: bytes -> string -> bytes with arbitrary binary data.

Comment: I overlooked that information from Wikipedia on their ISO-8859-1 page. Thanks for emphasizing it.

Comment: FYI I detailed why `new String(raf.readLine().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")` does the job when wanting to read UTF-8 text with `RandomAccessFile` and get a `String` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54433693/452614).

Answer (score 6):

For an encoding to retain original binary data, it needs to map every unique byte sequence to an unique character sequence.

This rules out all multi-byte encodings (UTF-8/16/32, Shift-Jis, Big5 etc) because not every byte sequence is valid in them
and thus would decode to some replacement character (usually ? or �). There is no way to tell from the string what caused
the replacement character after it has been decoded.

Another option is to ignore the invalid bytes but this also means that infinite different
byte sequences decode to the same string. You could replace invalid bytes with their hex encoding
in the string like `"0xFF"`. There is no way to tell if the original bytes legitimately decoded
to `"0xFF"` so that doesn't work either.

This leaves 8-bit encodings, where every sequence is just a single byte. The single byte is valid
if there is a mapping for it. But many 8-bit encodings have holes and don't encode 256 different characters.

To retain original binary data, you need 8-bit encoding that encodes 256 different characters. ISO-8859-1
is not unique in this. But what it is unique in, is that the decoded code point's value is also the byte's value 
it was decoded from.

So you have the decoded string, and encoded bytes, then it is always

```
(byte)str.charAt(i) == bytes[i]
```

for arbitrary binary data where `str` is `new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1")` and `bytes`
is a `byte[]`.

---

It also has nothing to do with Java. I have no idea what his comment means, these are properties of character encodings not programming languages.

Comment: The comment was meant to put this all in code perspective (notice also "In Java, ISO-8859-1 (a.k.a ISO-Latin1) is a 1:1 mapping")- aka I don't know how all this would look in C - very informative answer @JBNizet ("But what it is unique in, is that the decoded code point's value is also the byte's value it was decoded from") +1 :)