# Convert persian unicode to Ascii

Tags: encoding, ascii, persian

I need to get the ASCII code of a Persian string to use it in a program. But the method below give the ? marks: "??? ????"

```
public string PerisanAscii()
    {

        //persian string 
        string unicodeString = "صبح بخیر";

        // Create two different encodings.
        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

        // Convert the string into a byte array. 
        byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

        // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other. 
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

        // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string. 
        char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
        ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
        string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);

        return asciiString;
    }
```

Can you help me?

Best regards, 
Mohsen

Comment: It's not really possible since ASCII doesn't support Persian. What do you want to do with the ASCII string?

Comment: I need this method to use in AutoCAD.

Comment: In VBA, when I get a Persian text, in code Editor I see ? marks.

Comment: Well, you can't use ASCII. I don't know this for a fact but AutoCAD probably supports Unicode. If it doesn't you could try another encoding that supports Persian.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes() Returning Unexpected Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963421/asciiencoding-ascii-getbytes-returning-unexpected-value)

Answer (score 5):

You can convert Persian UTF8 data to Windows-1256 (Arabic Windows):

```
var enc1256 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
var data = enc1256.GetBytes(unicodeString);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

ASCII does not support Persian. You may need old school [Iran System encoding standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_System_encoding_standard). This is determined by your Autocad application. I don't know if there is a direct  Encoding in windows for it or not. But you can convert characters manually too. It's a simple mapping.