# Received data from SerialPort > 0x7F gets displayed as 0x3F

Tags: c#, serial-port, hex

I want to send randomly generated data from my PC to a µC (ATmega328p) and then mirror it back. For this purpose I wrote a program in C# (my first time working with it).

Every Byte the PC receives back which is >0xF7 gets displayed as 0x3F.

The µController receives and sends the data back correctly(I display all data which the µC receives and sends on an LCD). 
I also used two serial terminal tools ( HTerm, Pololu Serial Transmitter) to verify that the µC works fine.
There has to be something wrong when the PC receivs/displays the data at the end.

Display received data as .hex in textBox1

```
  private  void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){

        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        string outp = string.Empty;
        char[] value = indata.ToCharArray();
        foreach(char L in value){
        int V = Convert.ToInt32(L);
        outp+= string.Format("{0:x}",V);
        }

        if (outp != String.Empty)
            Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(outp)));
    }
```

Edit2//

I fixed the problem. Thanks to [kunif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014308/kunif) and [gunnerone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2263392/gunnerone) for the hints!
There seemed to be a problem with the encoding of port.ReadExisting(). Instead I know use the port.Read().

```
private  void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){

        int bytesToRead = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] value = new byte[bytesToRead];
        port.Read(value,0,bytesToRead);
        string indata = BitConverter.ToString(value);
        if (indata != String.Empty)
            Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(indata)));
    }
```

Comment: Somewhere your problem is being caused by someone encoding/decoding the bytes.  Everything above 0x7F gets changed to a 0x3F (question mark symbol).  If your program is sending 0x08 0x09 0x10, that's different than it sending "8910".  If you send your uC something like 0xFF what gets echoed back?

Comment: You are right, everything >0x7F gets echoed back as 0x3F. Kind of stupid not to see that, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

As in this article [ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes() Returning Unexpected Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963421/asciiencoding-ascii-getbytes-returning-unexpected-value), it seems that processing similar to Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() or ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes() is done somewhere (may be indata.ToCharArray()).

Please try change from `char[] value = indata.ToCharArray();` to `byte[] value = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(indata);`, also change other char[] to byte[].

Comment: The problem still occurs, but the article you linked makes sense. I'll look  into it later.