# Get Server info from gameserver (porting existing code)

Tags: c#

So i have this php code which i need to port to C#

```
 $socket = stream_socket_client('udp://'.$server , $errno, $errstr, 1);
    fwrite($socket, "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x67\x69\x65\x33\x05");
    $response = fread($socket, 2048);
```

And im trying to do the same thing in C#

```
        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          var client = new UdpClient();
          IPEndPoint ep = new 
          IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("censored"),censored);

          client.Connect(ep);

          Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x67\x69\x65\x33\x05");

          client.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);

          var received = client.Receive(ref ep);

          result.Text = received.ToString();
    }
```

But it just freezes and gets no response (timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x67\x69\x65\x33\x05");
> ```

This line will not produce the byte array that you would expect. As for why, it is explained here: [ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes() Returning Unexpected Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963421/asciiencoding-ascii-getbytes-returning-unexpected-value)

Try this instead:

```
var sendBytes = new byte[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x67, 0x69, 0x65, 0x33, 0x05 }
```