# App Engine ndb StringProperty and string hashes

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using PyCrypto for generating secure key hashes. I want to store one or more of the partial keys I generate. Each partial key is in the form

```
\x0f|4\xcc\x02b\xc3\xf8\xb0\xd8\xfc\xd4\x90VE\xf2
```

I have an ndb `StringProperty()` in which I'd lke to store that info. However, it raises a `BadValueError` saying it expects an UTF-8 encoded string. I tried using str's `.encode('uft-8')` method but that also raises an error telling me it couldn't encode because bad positioning.

Anyway, my question is, how can I convert that byte string into something I can store in ndb?

Comment: You could also base64 encode your hashes, and decode when you go to use them

Comment: Yes, I thought about it after I had changed stuff around. D'oh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Improved Answer:

In this case instead of storing the key as String or Text, you should use a `BlobProperty` which stores an uninterpreted byte string.

### Original Answer:

To convert bytes (strings) to unicode you use the method `decode`. You also need to use an encoding that preserves the original binary data, which is ISO-8859-1. See [ISO-8859-1 encoding and binary data preservation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925458/iso-8859-1-encoding-and-binary-data-preservation)

```
unicode_key = key.decode('iso-8859-1')
bytes_key = unicode_key.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

Consider also using A TextProperty instead, as StringProperties are indexed.

Comment: You would need to do unicode_key.encode('iso-8859-1') to get the original bytes. After some thought in this case the best option is to use a BlobProperty instead. See update.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using TextProperty since BlobProperty was expecting str and decoding and encoding to iso-8859-1 produced unicode